# NodeJs Mongodb: connect ECONNREFUSED <server-ip>:27017

Tags: node.js, mongodb

С одного сервера пытаюсь подключиться к MongoDB, которая находится на другом сервере. Все время получаю ошибку. Оба сервера на Ubuntu 18

Что я для этого сделал:

1. mongod.conf на удаленном сервере:

   ```
   bindIp: 127.0.0.1 <ip-сервера-с-nodejs>

   security: authorization: 'enabled'
   ```
2. Добавил пользователя-админа в mongoDB

MongoDB работает без ошибок.

Я пытаюсь подключиться к MongoDB, расположенной на другом сервере:

```
mongo_creds = {    
  url: "mongodb://<username>:<pwd>@<server ip>:27017",
  db: "test",
  coll: "test_coll",
}
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
const options = { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }
const mongoClient = new MongoClient(mongo_creds.url, options);
 
mongoClient.connect(function(err, dbClient) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("CONNECTION ERROR ------------")
    throw(err)
  } else {
    console.log("MongoDB Connected")
  }

})
```

После выполнения, я получаю ошибку:

```
MongoServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED <ip-удаленного-сервера>:27017
```

Файрвола нет, пинг до сервера с монго проходит. У меня не получается проверить соединение с помощью айпи и порта следующим образом:

```
root@ubuntu:~/# nc -vz <mongo-ip> 27017
nc: connect to <mongo-ip> port 27017 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
```

nmap не показывает 27017 порт

```
Nmap scan report for incognito.20d.uk (<mongo-ip>)
Host is up (0.0056s latency).
Not shown: 996 closed ports
PORT    STATE    SERVICE
22/tcp  open     ssh
25/tcp  filtered smtp
80/tcp  open     http
443/tcp open     https
```

Должен ли я в этой ситуации задать вопросу моему VPS провайдеру или дело не в нем?
Что я делаю не так? Спасибо!

**в рабочем коде использую реальные ip, логины и пароли*

Comment: а сам монго-сервер запущен? к монге можно поцепиться с машины на которой она установлена?

Comment: @nörbörnën да, там все работает. Хоть через Node, хоть через командную строку

Comment: а `netstat -ant | grep 27017` что говорит? может он только локалхост слушает

Comment: @nörbörnën Я плохо разбираюсь, но выглядит так, что только локалхост.
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN

Comment: @nörbörnën как сделать так, чтобы внешние запросы тоже слушались?

Comment: я не разбираюсь в настройках, но вот дока: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-mongodb-configuration/

Comment: в доке пишут, что можно перечислить адреса через `bindIp` или прописать `bindIpAll`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113200/discussion-between---and-norbornen).